# how to show plots saved with np.save() in an window external to the IPython console

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to save data and plots in a numpy file, for this purpose I provide an easy example as the following lines of code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = {}
ax = {}

fig[0] = plt.figure()
fig[1] = plt.figure()

ax[0] = fig[0].add_subplot(111)

ax[1] = fig[1].add_subplot(111)

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)

y = np.sin( np.pi*x) / (np.pi*x)

z = y**2

line1, = ax[0].plot(x, y)

line2, = ax[1].plot(x, z)

import os

path = r"C:\Users\fedel\Desktop\pythonScripts"

os.chdir(path)

fileName = 'prova.npy'

np.save(fileName, [x, y, z, ax, fig])
```

The final plots are respectively [image] and [image]

And I can easily show them in a window EXTERNAL to the spyder console as the graphics beckend is set in "Qt mode".

Now I if I open a new Spyder consol and I type

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
path = r"C:\Users\fedel\Desktop\pythonScripts"

os.chdir(path)
a = np.load(fileName)
```

I can easily get access to everything I saved, particulary, I can show a plot just typing

```
a[3][0]
```

or

```
a[4][0]
```

But the problem is that now there is no way to place the plots in a window OUT of the Spyder IPython console and I didn't modify the Spyder graphic beckend.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: `np.save` and `np.load` are designed primarily to handle `numpy` arrays.  So `x` is handled normally.  `fig` and `ax` are dictionaries that contain plot objects.  `np.save` resorts to `pickle` to handle those.  I'd suggest a web search of problems with pickling figures.  Seems it has limitations.

Comment: I agree that the support for pickled figures is limited.  However if you just want to save and open the figure to do some external modifications (similar to saving Matlab figures), you might want to take a look into a hobby-project I have been developing (@ Git: https://github.com/pathoren/FigureLoader).  For basic figure-modifications it works well, but it might not be compatible with too complicated figures.